# why corehandwriting called by libdispatch.dylib?

Tags: iphone, ios, instruments, handwriting

I have a weird problem here.

I use instrument to see my app's leak.

and I found that the corehandwriting function will be called by libdispatch.dylib and occupy a big

size of memory space.

but, if put this app on ipad and run, the libdispatch.dylib won't call corehandwriting.

I don't wanna use the corehandwriting function. I don't want it to occupy the memory space.

could anyone tell me why the corehandwriting will be called?

and how to make libdispatch.dylib not to call the corehandwriting?

thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

I'd never heard of anything called CoreHandwriting. Sparked my interest.

I can't duplicate this on my devices. But that's not too surprising: looking at the symbols in the library, this looks like it's meant for chinese/kanji character recognition which I don't have turned on on my phone.

I wonder if you have handwriting enabled on one device and not on the other?

See http://thisfinger.com/support/enable_handwriting

Comment: yes!
the handwriting is set to the first keyboard of one device, but not of the other.
if I move the handwriting out off the first keyboard, there won't have this issue again!
thanks!!